# Java - appending & passing values

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with passing a string and double to another class because it keeps on crashing at double cost = input.nextDouble();. Also, i was wondering if i am correct with the appending method used in public boolean addPARTDETAILS(String partDESCRIPTION, double partCOST).

For example. If the user enters the parts and cost, i want it to store that in a list and print it out with the cost appended.

Parts used:

- brake pads ($50.00)
- brake fluids ($25.00)

Note. Assuming that i have declared all variables and the array.

```
System.out.print("Enter registration number of vehicle");
                String inputREGO = input.next();
                boolean flag = false;
                for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
                    if(inputREGO.equalsIgnoreCase(services[i].getregoNUMBER())){
                        System.out.print("Enter Part Description: ");
                        String parts = input.nextLine();
                        double cost = input.nextDouble();

                        services[i].addPARTDETAILS(parts, cost);


                        //System.out.println(services[i].getregoNUMBER());
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }if(flag==false);
                System.out.println("No registration number were found in the system.");

public boolean addPARTDETAILS(String partDESCRIPTION, double partCOST){
    if(partDESCRIPTION == "" || partCOST <= 0){
        System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again!");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        partCOST=0;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(40);
        String[] parts = new String[50];
        for (int i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
            partDESCRIPTION = sb.append(partCOST).toString();
        }
        System.out.println(partDESCRIPTION);


        totalPART+=partCOST;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `partDESCRIPTION == ""` this is not correkt, it should be `"".equals(partDESCRIPTION)` this will be safe also when `partDESCRIPTION` is null

Comment: @A4L [`isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) would be the better way (although it doesn't account for the `null` case)

Comment: @Dukeling the best is to write something like `isNotNullOrEmptyTrimed(String s)` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand a bit on Joop Eggen's and Peter Lawrey's answers because I feel some may not understand.

**`nextLine` doesn't play well with others:**

`nextDouble` is likely throwing a `NumberFormatException` because:

`next`, `nextInt`, `nextDouble`, etc. won't read the following end-of-line character, so `nextLine` will read the rest of the line and `nextDouble` will read the wrong thing.

**Example:** (`|` indicates current position)

Start:

```
|abc
123
def
456
```

After `nextLine`:

```
abc
|123
def
456
```

After `nextDouble`:

```
abc
123|
def
456
```

After `nextLine` (which reads the rest of the line, which contains nothing):

```
abc
123
|def
456
```

Now `nextDouble` tries to read `"def"`, which won't work.

**If-statement issues:**

```
if(flag==false);
```

or, rewritten:

```
if(flag==false)
  ;
```

is an if statement with an empty body. Thus the statement following will always execute. And no need to do `== false`, `!flag` means the same. What you want:

```
if (!flag)
  System.out.println("No registration number were found in the system.");
```

**String comparison with ==:**

```
partDESCRIPTION == ""
```

should be:

```
partDESCRIPTION.equals("")
```

or better:

```
partDESCRIPTION.isEmpty()
```

because `==` check whether the strings actually point to the exact same object (which won't happen unless you assign the one to the other with `=` at some point, either directly or indirectly), not just whether the have the same text (which is what `equals` is for).

Answer (score 2):

> it keeps on crashing at double cost = input.nextDouble();.

It is highly unlikely that your JVM is crashing.  It is far more likely that you are getting an Exception which you are not reading carefully enough and have forgotten to include in your question.

It is far more likely your code is incorrect as you may have mis-understood how scanner works. And so when you attempt to read a double, there is not a double in the input.  I suspect you want to call nextLine() after readDouble() to consume the rest of the the line.

I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to get a better understanding of what it is really doing.

Answer (score 1):

Data dependent error.

```
if(flag==false);
System.out.println("No registration number were found in the system.");
```

should be (because of the `;`):

```
if (!flag) {
    System.out.println("No registration number was found in the system.");
}
```

And

```
partDESCRIPTION == ""
```

should be:

```
partDESCRIPTION.isEmpty()
```